# Does not $(100x+51)^2-1$ end in $4$ zeros?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$$(100x+51)^2-1$$
For when $x$ is a real positive interger.
Prove or disprove that the expression  doea not end in four zeros or equivalently be in the equation  $1000y$ (where $y$ is a real positive interger)

Comment: This is $$(100x+50)(100x+52).$$

Comment: @lord-shark-the-unknown correct.

Comment: Indeed, but it suggests how to extract more factors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out in other answers,

$$(100x + 51)^2 - 1 = 10000x^2 + 10200x + 2600$$

So to find a value ending in 4 zeroes, you need $200x + 2600 = 10000$ , or $x = 37$ (plus any multiple of $50$).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use modular arithmetic (if you are thinking about it).

$(100x+51)^2-1=10000x^2+2\times 100x\times 51+2601-1=10000x^2+10200x+2600$, definitely not necessary ending with $4$ zeroes.

With $x=37$: $$(100x+51)^2-1=(100\times37+51)^2-1=3751^2-1=14070001-1=14070000$$

Comment: Unfortunately I've changed the question to does not so your answer only proves examples. @Trần Thúc Minh Trí

Comment: @PintOfMilk I have edited with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Take $x=77$ then we have $$(100\cdot 77+51)^2-1=60078000$$ this ends with three Zeros.

Comment: Can you find a counter example for four?

Comment: As @DanielV mentioned in his answer, your counters are when $x=37+50k, k\in \Bbb Z$, i.e. $37,87,137...$